# evaluation variables as object names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to evaluate a variable as an objects name and then retrieve the values of particular names within the object.

The object:

```
var priority = [{dSubDue:'1,D', dMS2date:"1.5,'M'", dMS3date:'3,M',dMS4date:'30,D',dMS5date:'1,M',dNotErFac:'2,W',dDOverview:'N/A',dPreACMResp:'2,W',dACMdate:'2,W',dMS6date:'2,W',dMS7date:'1,M',dM86date:'1.5M'}];
```

where the name of the object is `priority`.

When another variable, `cellval`, is set to the same name as the object `"priority"` I need to access the key values in actual priority object by using the following `cellval[0]['dMS2date']`.

If I use `eval(cellval[0]['dMS2date'])` it returns the correct values but if possible I'd prefer not to use eval.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  none of the apparent answers addresses the issue

Comment: it's very clear in the explanation. read it